# C passing by reference, single and multi-dimensional

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, pass-by-reference

Ok, I know this will probably be flagged as a duplicate, but I've searched everywhere and not been able to figure this out, so please bear with me.

Let me start off by saying that this is for a homework assignment, so I cannot change the function parameter types.

Also, I am not allowed to use ***any*** libraries (well, inside the function that does the changing).

### Part 1

---

First, how would I accomplish this:

```
void changeMe(char* s, int size) {
   //Change s to be "Hello, World!"
}

int main(void) {
   char* c;
   changeMe(c, 13);
   printf("%s", c); //Print out "Hello, World!"
}
```

(The homework doesn't call for the "Hello, World!" bit, but I don't need help with the logic, just changing the passed variable.)

I have looked all over, and most answers end up like this one [here](http://www.example.com), which says that I need the parameter to be `char** s`, or `char*& s` in order to change it.

Is my only choice to assume that enough memory is already allocated to s before it is passed? For example:

```
void changeMe(char* s, int size) {
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) s[i] = 'a';
   s[size - 1] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
   char* c = (char*) malloc(10 * sizeof(char)) ;
   changeMe(c, 10);
   printf("%s", c); //Prints out "aaaaaaaaa"
}
```

This works fine, but removing the `malloc(...)` from the declaration of `c` doesn't.

Putting `malloc(...)` inside of the `changeMe(...)` function works locally, but only lasts as long as `changeMe` is in scope.

Is there a way to change my `char* c` without assuming it has enough memory allocated to it before it is passed to the function?

### Part 2

---

This pretty much falls right into the same exact category as what is above, so I will do a bit less explaining here.

The function:

```
void split(char* s, char** sub, int max, char sep) {
   //Split string s by sep char, store all substrings found into sub
   //sub will have at most max substrings in it.
}
```

I am not asking for help writing the logic of finding and splitting up `char* s` by `char c`. I can do that. My issue is primarily the same as above. How do I allocate memory to `char** sub` so that it can fit all of the substrings in it (and, of course, change the variable passed).

For example:

```
void split(char* s, char** sub, int max, char sep) {
   //-->(Needed) Make sub able to hold max strings.
   //(Not Needed) Logic for splitting s up by sep, creating a substring.
   //-->(Needed) Making sub[i] have memory to hold current substring.
}

int main(void) {
   char* s = "Some String To Use";
   char** subs;
   split(s, subs, 10, ' ');
   //subs should look like this:
   //{"Some", "String", "To", "Use"}
}
```

I don't need help doing the actual work, I am just confused as to how to pass `subs` into `split(...)` and have it allocate the appropriate memory and change `subs`.

### Fin

---

If you have made it this far through my question, thank you for reading.

And, before all of the "did you try google" comments come in, yes. Here some of what I have looked at so far:

(Edit: Thanks, haccks, for adding hyperlinks for me.)

- [netcom](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm)
- [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcpy)
- [char-pointer-function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2227077/2455888)

  - Says to change parameter to char** or char*&. I don't have that luxory.
- [Pass By Reference Multidimensional Array With Unknown Size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15245309/2455888)

Again, if I was writing this for myself, I would change the parameters (`char** s` instead of `char* s` for example), and use nice, useful functions like `strcpy`, etc, but I cannot do that in this case. Any help/input would be very appreciated, thank you all so much in advance!

Comment: given that you must change the contents of parameter (char *), this must be preallocated and then you can use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) or similar to write (change) into the (char *) object

Comment: That is what I'm hoping is the case, because that is the only way I can think of doing this. I am still confused on the sub** part though.

Comment: 1. Not without changing the caller side to provide a valid buffer, or the receiver side to accept a pointer-to-pointer (or in C++ a reference-to-pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1**

The whole point of the `size` parameter is for the function `changeMe()` to know the size of the buffer.  You do not need to assume the size as, typically, such a function would be used as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int size;
    char* c;

    // some code to calculate the required size of the buffer in bytes
    size = calculateRequiredSize();

    // allocate the buffer
    c = ( char* )malloc( size );

    changeMe( c, size );
}
```

However, in response to your question, in the function `changeMe()` there is no way to change the data stored in the buffer without assuming that a memory buffer of `size` bytes has already been allocated.

**Part 2**

The same logic goes in here, although it is split (pun intended) in 2 parts.

Simply modifying your example, you would do the following:

```
void split(char* s, char** sub, int max, char sep) {

    char*   pCurrent;   // pointer to the beginning of the current substring inside the original string.
    int     lenCurrent; // length of the current substring

    // Making sub[i] have memory to hold current substring.
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < max; ++i )
    {
        //(Not Needed) Logic for splitting s up by sep, creating a substring.
        // OK -> I leave it to you.

        sub[i] = (char *)malloc( lenCurrent + 1 );  // use length of the current substring + an extra space for the terminating NULL character

        // I will leave it to you to copy the substring to sub[i]
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char* s = "Some String To Use";
    int max = 10; // Decide the value of max out here.
    char** subs = (char**)malloc( max * sizeof( char* ) );
    // Make subs able to hold max strings.
    split(s, subs, max, ' ');
    //subs should look like this:
    //{"Some", "String", "To", "Use"}
}
```

Comment: He said that he is not allowed to use any library calls in the function, so I think `malloc` in the split() function is forbidden...

Comment: I am pretty sure I cannot use malloc, but I think I am allowed to change the input string, so I can do as ElyashivLavi suggested, and change the occurrences of the separating token to '\0' and have subs[i] point to their respective place. Thank you, ajcaruana, for your extremely helpful input.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck with your homework! Att least you were honest enough to admit you are doing homework here... :)

**Regards Part 2:**

Sub is actually an array of char* - `(char *sub[max])`.

So you need to go over s, find where to split and what is the size of the splitted part. After that, allocate the needed size in the sub[] array. In this way, you will allocate exactly the amount you need.

**Another solution:**
In case you are not allowed to use `malloc()`, you can change *s string. Go over it, and change every occurrence of `sep` to `'\0'`. Then point the correct `sub[i]` pointer to the beginning of the string. This is actually how `strsep()` works.

*Demonstartion:*

Let's say that `s` is `"Hello-World-This-Is-Homework"`.
Then set `sub[0]` to point to `s[0]`, which is the beginning of the first part. The go over `s` until the next `'-'`. Change it to `'\0'`. Then point `s[1]` to the beginning of `"World"`, and change the next `'-'` to `'\0'`, etc...

**Regards Part 1:**

After you've told us that in part 2 you received an already-allocated array, I assume that in part 1 the array is also already allocated. So you actually have `char s[size]`. So it seems that your solution is correct - if the user passed wrong element in size, this is his fault. You cannot verify it.

Comment: I would up-vote if I could (not enough reputation). I think I am going to assume that there is already memory allocated, and, as you suggest, change each sub[i] to point to a location in the string. Thank you so much for your input!

Answer (score 0):

When you modify an array (pointer) passed as a parameter to a function, you  modify it's content in caller too. That's because C works by copying parameters, but in this case it copies the pointer, not the value it points to. So, you need to modify the value that pointer points to in your function, without having to pass the pointer in a special way. But, note that in order to be able to access and modify the memory, it has to be allocated in the caller function. That is why you can not remove malloc.

Comment: Judging from all of the answers and everything I've read, I think it is safe to assume that my functions will be supplied with parameters that already have memory allocated to them. Thanks for helping clarify that for me.

Answer (score 0):

part 1

if your function prototype changeMe(char* s, int size) cannot be changed
then your only option is to provide the function with a buffer that is large
enough to accommodate your new string,

```
void changeMe( char* s, int size )
{
  if ( s != NULL && s > 0 )
  {
    char* p = strncpy( s, "Hello, World", size-1 ); // assuming size includes \0
    if ( p != NULL )
    {
      p[size - 1] = '\0'; // make sure it is 0 terminated.
    }
  }
}
```

the reason why you need "char** s" as a parameter to change
the size is that char* s means that the address is passed to
the function by value i.e. a copy of the original address
similar to if you would have passed say an int:

```
void foo(int n) // n is a copy of the original value
{
  n = 1; // modifying the copy
}
```

the value of n would not change outside foo but if you write

```
void foo(int* n) // n is now pointing to the original value
{
  *n = 1; // changing what n points to i.e. the original value
}
```

when it comes to strings it is the same principle just with one
more level of indirection

```
void foo(char* s)
{
  s = "hello"; // just temporarily changes what the copy s points to, not the original
}

void foo(char** s)
{
  *s = malloc(10); // changes what the original s points to
}
```

Part 2

Hint: look at realloc(), that function works as malloc but expands the memory block 
dynamically

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use any library functions inside my changeMe and split functions, so malloc and realloc are off the table (and, unfortunately, strcpy). However, your answer was very informative and did help clarify things for me. Thanks for the response.